# display Webpart Title on 2 lines

Tags: web-part, content-query-web-part, html

I have a little question for you:

I would like to display Webpart Title in 2 lines.
So, from

```
My Superbe Webpart Title
```

going to

```
My Superbe
Webpart Title
```

Simple, right?

So i tried it, but i always end up with a word wrap and "..."
I checked the HTML Structure, and the title is encapsulated in a `<nobr>` tag!
*Which are obsolete (better to do white space and wordwrap in css).*

Could you help me to know **where the title HTML is generated**, and to know **how i could manage to display my webpart titles on 2 lines**?

Thanks a lot.

Gaëlle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can grab the offending `NOBR` element via JavaScript, you can then hide it and insert a less offensive element adjacent to it with the same (or modified) HTML content.

```
// 1. grab the NOBR tag via CSS selector
var nobr = document.querySelector(".ms-standardheader.ms-WPTitle nobr");
// NOTE: Replace above CSS Selector with one that grabs the title of your web part
// 2. hide the NOBR tag
nobr.style.display = "none"; 
// 3. add a span tag with the same contents
nobr.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend","<span>"+nobr.innerHTML+"</span>");
```

Note that you could do additional manipulation to the HTML content by messing around with `nobr.innerHTML` before you call `insertAdjacentHTML()`

Note also that if you want to manipulate multiple web part titles that match a specified query selector, you can use `var nobrs = document.querySelectorAll("...");` and then loop through the resulting element array.

Comment: Hi @Thriggle! Thanks a lot for your answer, though i already tried some dirty code (like a dirty javascript to remove <nobr> elements and some css to make my title going 2 lines)
You wrote a very documented and complete answer, so thanks a lot for that, it will surely help me later!